# Finding anagrams using dictionary in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a function in python that will print out the anagrams of words in a text file using dictionaries. I've looked at what feels like hundreds of similar questions, so I apologise if this is a repetition, but I can't seem to find a solution that fits my issue.

I understand what I need to do (at least, I think so), but I'm stuck on the final part.

This is what I have so far:

```
with open('words.txt', 'r') as fp:
    line = fp.readlines()

def make_anagram_dict(line):
    dict = {}
    for word in line:
        key = ''.join(sorted(word.lower()))
        if key in dict.keys():
            dict[key].append(word.lower())
        else:
            dict[key] = []
            dict[key].append(word.lower())
    if line == key:
        print(line)


make_anagram_dict(line)
```

I think I need something which compares the key of each value to the keys of other values, and then prints if they match, but I can't get something to work.

At the moment, the best I can do is print out all the keys and values in the file, but ideally, I would be able to print all the anagrams from the file.

Output: I don't have a concrete specified output, but something along the lines of:
    [cat: act, tac]

for each anagram. 
Again, apologies if this is a repetition, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Once you've processed all the entries in the file, the dict keys with multiple values associated to them represent anagrams.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please share a snippet for input format and expected output along with the code?

Comment: Question for you: when you say "[find] anagrams of words in a text file using dictionaries," do you mean A.) you're supposed to find the words in this document which are anagrams of each other & group them in `dict`s, B.) you're supposed to print all permutations of the letters of these words and store your results in a `dict`, or C.) (I have a hunch this might be the problem:) Find & use an actual digital dictionary to see which have the same letters as those from your input file?

Comment: I may have worded that badly. I'd like to be able to print the words in the file which are anagrams of other words in the file, if that makes sense.

Comment: It does. Working on an answer for ya.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about the output format. In my implementation, all anagrams are printed out in the end.

```
with open('words.txt', 'r') as fp:
    line = fp.readlines()

def make_anagram_dict(line):
    d = {}  # avoid using 'dict' as variable name

    for word in line:
        word = word.lower()  # call lower() only once
        key = ''.join(sorted(word))
        if key in d:  # no need to call keys()
            d[key].append(word)
        else:
            d[key] = [word]  # you can initialize list with the initial value

    return d  # just return the mapping to process it later

if __name__ == '__main__':
    d = make_anagram_dict(line)

    for words in d.values():
        if len(words) > 1:  # several anagrams in this group
            print('Anagrams: {}'.format(', '.join(words)))
```

---

Also, consider using `defaultdict` - it's a dictionary, that creates values of a specified type for fresh keys.

```
from collections import defaultdict

with open('words.txt', 'r') as fp:
    line = fp.readlines()

def make_anagram_dict(line):
    d = defaultdict(list)  # argument is the default constructor for value

    for word in line:
        word = word.lower()  # call lower() only once
        key = ''.join(sorted(word))
        d[key].append(word)  # now d[key] is always list

    return d  # just return the mapping to process it later

if __name__ == '__main__':
    d = make_anagram_dict(line)

    for words in d.values():
        if len(words) > 1:  # several anagrams in this group
            print('Anagrams: {}'.format(', '.join(words)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to make the assumption you're grouping words within a file which are anagrams of eachother.

If, on the other hand, you're being asked to find all the English-language anagrams for a list of words in a file, you will need a way of determining what is or isn't a word. This means you either need an actual "dictionary" as in a `set(<of all english words>)` or a maybe a *very* sophisticated predicate method.

Anyhow, here's a relatively straightforward solution which assumes your `words.txt` is small enough to be read into memory completely:

```
with open('words.txt', 'r') as infile:
    words = infile.read().split()

anagram_dict = {word : list() for word in words}

for k, v in anagram_dict.items():
     k_anagrams = (othr for othr in words if (sorted(k) == sorted(othr)) and (k != othr))
     anagram_dict[k].extend(k_anagrams)

print(anagram_dict)
```

This isn't the most efficient way to do this, but hopefully it gets accross the power of filtering.

Arguably, the most important thing here is the `if (sorted(k) == sorted(othr)) and (k != othr)` filter in the `k_anagrams` definition. This is a filter which only allows identical letter-combinations, but weeds out exact matches.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is pretty much there, just needs some tweaks:

```
import re

def make_anagram_dict(words):
    d = {}  
    for word in words:
        word = word.lower()          # call lower() only once
        key = ''.join(sorted(word))  # make the key
        if key in d:  # check if it's in dictionary already
            if word not in d[key]:   # avoid duplicates
                d[key].append(word)
        else:
            d[key] = [word]  # initialize list with the initial value
    return d                         # return the entire dictionary

if __name__ == '__main__':
    filename = 'words.txt'
    with open(filename) as file:
        # Use regex to extract words. You can adjust to include/exclude 
        # characters, numbers, punctuation...
        # This returns a list of words
        words = re.findall(r"([a-zA-Z\-]+)", file.read())

    # Now process them 
    d = make_anagram_dict(words)  

    # Now print them
    for words in d.values():
        if len(words) > 1:  # we found anagrams
            print('Anagram group {}: {}'.format(', '.join(words)))
```

Comment: NameError: name 'i' is not defined

Comment: My mistake: remnant from another iteration. Should work now.